# Rails: How to disable asterisk on form's required fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, simple-form

When I add the 'Required' attribute
to html input fields, Rails pre-pends an asterisk (*) before the label.

Does anyone know how to prevent this?

For some reason Rails transforms this:

```
<%= f.input :Company, :input_html => {:value => "", :id => "company_name"}, :label => "company name" %>
```

into this:

```
<div class="input string required">
    <label for="company_name" class="string required">
    <abbr title="required">*</abbr> company name</label>
    <input type="text" value="" size="50" required="required" name="lead[Company]" id="company_name" class="string required">
</div>
```

I don't like that it wraps everything in a DIV and adds an ABBR element to the party.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Can you please post the code that you are speaking about?  That would help.

Comment: @Lester Peabody - I've updated the question with my code example

Comment: Are you using gems like `formtastic` or `simple_form`? Please post your `Gemfile`.

Comment: If you're using the `formtastic` gem, [here is how to remove the asterisks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16865104/806956).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In config/initializers/simple_form.rb add this line:

```
config.label_text = lambda { |label, required| "#{label}" }
```

Comment: I had to both uncomment the line from the initializer field and change html: '' in the yaml file in my locales directory. FWIW, I am using simple_form with devise and bootstrap. Don't know or thinks that makes a difference though

Comment: I've tried the locale solution and didn't work, but this one did. I'm using simple_form 2.0.4

Comment: Using 3.0-RC2, I used this:  config.label_text = lambda { |label, required, explicit_label| "#{label}" }

Comment: Still not working for me. With devise 3.0.3, Rails 3.2.13, no chance, the `config.label_text` is completely ignored.

Comment: Remember you need to restart your Rails server after editing an initializer file.

Comment: Is it possible remove the asterisk on a per-form basis?

Comment: @art-solopov for that I just pass `defaults: { required: false }` as a form option.

Comment: The following works with SimpleForm 3.5.0: `lambda { |label, required, explicit_label| "#{label}" }`. Note the inclusion of the `explicit_label` argument.

Answer (score 53):

You can just set the required mark to empty value in simple_form's locale file:

```
en:
  simple_form:
    required:
      text: 'required'
      mark: '*'
```

Or use CSS to hide it.

Comment: would that create en empty html element? because that would be an highly unwanted result.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore - you now need to uncomment the "html" line underneath (or add it if you don't already have it), then set that to `html: ''`

Comment: This is the answer!, In case anybody else wonders, you should create a file name simple_form.en.yml under config/locales/

Comment: No need to uncomment the html, but you do have to restart the server.

Comment: You end up with whitespace using this approach: the `<abbr></abbr>` tag is still rendered.

Answer (score 22):

I'm using Rails 3.1, and I have the following view code in my _form.html.erb for a given model:

```
<div>
  <%= f.label :full_name %><br/>
  <%= f.text_field :full_name, :required => true %><br/>
</div>
```

The label does not show an asterisk if you do it this way.  Unless you post code I can't be sure of what your approach is and if my solution would fit said approach.

Updated Answer:
It sounds like you've inherited this code from someone.  At any rate, after reading your code sample, you are most definitely using the simple_form gem.  Information about that gem can be found here https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form.  To answer your question though, if you change your code the following:

```
<%= f.input :Company, :input_html => {:value => "", :id => "company_name"}, :label => "company name", :required => false %>
```

That should turn off the asterisk.

I would add, based on your disgust for the HTML generated from simple_form, it sounds like you should just do away with the gem and re-write your form code using the Rails default form helpers, which can be read about here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html.  Depending on the size of the code base, you might be better off just sucking it up and learning how to use the simple_form gem for the sake of saving time, but if you think you have the time to change it all, go for it.

Comment: thanks, I will try splitting it. currently I use it as one line combined, maybe cause of that.

Comment: No problem, if this worked for you make sure to upvote and mark it as the accepted answer so other folks can benefit.

Comment: I don't understand, for some reason RoR thinks all fields are require by default

Comment: @vsync: I've updated my answer to reflect the code you provided in your updated answer.  This should be all that you need, let me know if you need additional help.

Comment: I up-voted for this answer, and will have to verify it only next week when the other developer in my office comes back.

Comment: I figured you didn't downvote it as I was trying to help :) someone else did though... *shakes fist*

Answer (score 16):

The simplest way is to hide it with this css:

```
abbr[title="required"] {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It isn't rails at all. It's the [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) gem. So, if you don't want all the wrapping elements don't use simple_form. Use Rails form [helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html). It would be more simple than customize something you don't like.

Comment: But what if you want to use simple_form and just want to disable the asterisk?  Most people who come to this question are probably using simple_form and want to keep it

Answer (score 4):

For anyone using Formtastic and having this issue, you can remove the asterisks by editing the config file, which is typically **app/config/initializers/formtastic.rb**.

Change this line: `# Formtastic::SemanticFormBuilder.required_string = "(required)"`

to be: `Formtastic::SemanticFormBuilder.required_string = ""`

More info [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/formtastic/v4aSugFWWiw).

Answer (score 3):

Code that has helped me solve the asterisk issue:

```
abbr[title="required"] {
  display: none;
}
```

The chosen answer and the other suggestions asking to change the HTML in locales file dint help me with the latest Simple_form gem.

Comment: where does one add this code, in a simple_form, bootstrap configuration? Thx

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the global config suggested in the accepted answer, you can pass `required: false` as an input option, or `defaults: { required: false }` to set it for the whole form.

Comment: Others already said this in [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7651132/104380) from 6 years ago.. you do not provide any new insights to this old matter..

Comment: Yes I did: how to set it for the whole form. My answer is also very brief, which is good.

Comment: That is true, the part where you mention the `defaults` is indeed fresh information

Answer (score 3):

You can remove it from the whole form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @form, defaults: { required: false } do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that if you only want to remove the asterisk(*) behind it then all you have to  do is to go to this file `file /config/locales/simple_form.en.yml`

once again is not a good practice to change your configuration files for gems and something your using for some reason, it always a question of why do you really use simple_form!

But for example I found out about that because there is great things about simple_form we use but nowadays is a better usability practice to have the asterisks on none required fields then required ones.

Answer (score 0):

you can used `form_for`, and override method `def label` in `config/initializer` to add asterisk for mandatory fields as the following:

```
def label(object_name, method, content_or_options = nil, options = nil, &block)
    if content_or_options.is_a?(Hash)

      content_or_options.each do |key, val|
        options[key] = val
      end

      content_or_options = method.to_s
    end

    content_or_options ||= method.to_s

    presence_validations = [ActiveModel::Validations::PresenceValidator, ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator]

    class_obj = options[:object].class if options[:object]
    class_obj ||= object_name.to_s.camelize.constantize

    validations = class_obj.validators_on(method.to_s).map(&:class)

    if (presence_validations.map { |pv| validations.include?(pv) }).any?
      content_or_options += "*"
    end

    Tags::Label.new(object_name, method, self, content_or_options, options).render(&block)
end
```

This method puts asterisk after all mandatory fields, if you used normal `form_for`, and used `validates_presence_of`