# Asterisk character " * " in simple form Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

i am using the simple form gem and the inputs labels shows an Asterisk " * " before text and i do not need that

something like:
*Year
*Month
*Week
*Quantity

simple form view:

```
<%= simple_form_for @tech_evaluation do |f| %>
<%= f.input :year, label: "Año", collection: 2017..2020 %>

<%= f.association :project, label: "Proyecto" %>
<%= f.association :countable_account, label: "Cuenta contable" %>
<%= f.association :item %>
<%= f.input :unit_cost, label: "Costo unidario" %>
<%= f.input :unit, label: "Unidad de medida", collection: [ "C/U" ] %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible duplicate of [How to disable asterisk on form's required fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650689/how-to-disable-asterisk-on-forms-required-fields)

If you want to disable asterisks for that form only, pass `defaults: { required: false }` into `simple_form_for`:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@tech_evaluation, defaults: { required: false }) do |f| %>
# ...
```

Or you can disable it even for just a single input element:

```
<%= f.input :year, label: "Año", collection: 2017..2020, required: false %>
```

Read more at [Simple Form: Usage](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#usage)

Lastly, if you want to disable the asterisk mark for ALL simple forms, you can do so by creating the file `simple_form.en.yml` under `config/locales/` with this content:

```
# config/locales/simple_form.en.yml
en:
  simple_form:
    required:
      text: 'required'
      mark: '*'
      # This will overwrite required text and mark for all simple forms.
      # When using html, text and mark won't be used.
      # Comment out the line below to return to default settings.
      html: ''
```

See more configuration options at [simple_form.en.yml on Gituhb](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/c3a307cb9501208e053f771738e34a3d93d33858/lib/generators/simple_form/templates/config/locales/simple_form.en.yml)

Comment: it's works correctly, thank you very much